# Gulp tasks chaining

Tags: gulp, browser-sync, gulp-livereload

I'm using gulp to compile some .less files and inject the changes in the browser with live-reload.

This is the task I originally created:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var path = require('path');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core');
var mqpacker = require('css-mqpacker');
var csswring = require('csswring');

gulp.task('less', function() {
  var processors = [
    autoprefixer({browsers: ["last 2 version", "> 1%", "ie 9", "ie 8", "ie 7", "ios 6"]}),
    mqpacker,
    csswring({
      preserveHacks: true,
      removeAllComments: true
    })
  ];
  gulp.src('./css/style.less')  // only compile the entry file
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(less({
    paths: ['./css/'],
  } ))
  .pipe(postcss(processors))
  .pipe(plumber.stop())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
  .pipe(livereload());
});
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./**/*.less', ['less']);  // Watch all the .less files, then run the less task
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']); // Default will run the 'entry' watch task
```

I created an other gulp task to perform the same tasks but using browser-sync instead of live-reload for cross testing:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var path = require('path');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core');
var csswring = require('csswring');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('less', function() {
  var processors = [
    autoprefixer({browsers: ["last 2 version", "> 1%", "ie 9", "ie 8", "ie 7", "ios 6"]}),
    csswring({
      preserveHacks: true,
      removeAllComments: true
    })
  ];
  gulp.src('./css/style.less')  // only compile the entry file
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(less({
    paths: ['./css/']
  } ))
  .pipe(postcss(processors))
  .pipe(plumber.stop())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
  .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
  // .pipe(livereload());
});
gulp.task('serve', ['less'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "http://my-site.dev/"
    });

    gulp.watch("./css/*.less", ['less']);
});
```

I then tried to compile both files to be able to run either task depending on if i'm doing local development or if testing. I've created a "less" task to compile the css, a "lrl" live reload watch task and a "bs" browser-sync watch task. I created the "less" task to remove the duplication but now when i change the css the browser reload everything instead of just injecting the css.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var path = require('path');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core');
var csswring = require('csswring');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var reload = browserSync.reload;

gulp.task('less', function() {
  var processors = [
    autoprefixer({browsers: ["last 2 version", "> 1%", "ie 9", "ie 8", "ie 7", "ios 6"]}),
    csswring({
      preserveHacks: true,
      removeAllComments: true
    })
  ];
  gulp.src('./css/style.less')  // only compile the entry file
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(less({
    paths: ['./css/']
  } ))
  .pipe(postcss(processors))
  .pipe(plumber.stop())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
});

gulp.task('lrl',['less'], function(){
  gulp.src('./css/style.less')  // only compile the entry file
  .pipe(livereload());
});


gulp.task('watch',['lrl'], function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('./**/*.less', ['lrl']);  // Watch all the .less files, then run the less task
});


// browser-sync setup
gulp.task('bs',['less'], function(){
  gulp.src('./css/style.less')  // only compile the entry file
  .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "http://my-site.dev/"
    });
    gulp.watch("./css/*.less", ['bs']);
    gulp.watch("./js/script.js").on('change', reload);
    gulp.watch("./templates/*.php").on('change', reload);
});

// run default task with live reload for local development
gulp.task('default', ['watch']); // Default will run the 'entry' watch task
```

I'm a bit confused with the way to call tasks within tasks. Is there a way to make sure that the css are injected, it's much faster to work on design this way.

Thanks a lot

=================== BIG EDIT ============================

I've been messing about with run-sequence but I still have the same problem.
In some way the task is working. With the default task i get live-reload on my local server only. With `gulp serve` I get a server where i can debug my layout across browsers and devices. The problem is that i don't get css injection anymore. it looks like gulp keeps re-running all of the tasks and refresh the browser to reconnect it.

so I made a working version with duplicated code to make what i'm trying to achieve clearer

```
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    less         = require('gulp-less'),
    watch        = require('gulp-watch'),
    plumber      = require('gulp-plumber'),
    path         = require('path'),
    postcss      = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core'),
    mqpacker     = require('css-mqpacker'),
    csswring     = require('csswring'),
    livereload   = require('gulp-livereload'),
    browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create(),
    reload       = browserSync.reload;


gulp.task('less-lrl', function() {
  var processors = [
    autoprefixer({browsers: ["last 2 version", "> 1%", "ie 9", "ie 8", "ie 7", "ios 6"]}),
    mqpacker,
    csswring({
      preserveHacks: true,
      removeAllComments: true
    })
  ];
  gulp.src('./css/style.less')  // only compile the entry file
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(less({
    paths: ['./css/'],
  } ))
  .pipe(postcss(processors))
  .pipe(plumber.stop())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
  .pipe(livereload());
});
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('./**/*.less', ['less-lrl']);  // Watch all the .less files, then run the less task
});


gulp.task('less-bs', function() {
  var processors = [
    autoprefixer({browsers: ["last 2 version", "> 1%", "ie 9", "ie 8", "ie 7", "ios 6"]}),
    mqpacker,
    csswring({
      preserveHacks: true,
      removeAllComments: true
    })
  ];
  gulp.src('./css/style.less')  // only compile the entry file
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(less({
    paths: ['./css/']
  } ))
  .pipe(postcss(processors))
  .pipe(plumber.stop())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
  .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});
gulp.task('serve', ['less-bs'], function() {

  browserSync.init({
    proxy: "http://myserver.dev"
  });

  gulp.watch("./css/*.less", ['less-bs']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']); // Default will run the 'entry' watch task
```

When I do this it works smoothly. But I wanted to avoid the code duplication from the "less-lrl" and "less-bs" tasks. The only thing that differ is `.pipe(livereload());` and `.pipe(reload({stream: true}))`

There's some stoopid going on in my brain, i don't haz understand :)

Comment: Read - http://www.sitepoint.com/build-css-preprocessor-postcss/

Comment: My gulpfile is a mess because i'm trying stuff to understand :). I don't want to Use postcss as a replacement for less yet (doing this for work and we all use less ). I've been recommended postcss to handle autoprefixer. Since then i discovered some nice plugin that i like to use so i stick to it. Thanks for the link.

Comment: have you tried what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: Yes i did but to no avail.

Comment: Actually, i'm trying again. I had to change back `gulp.src('./**/*.less)` to `gulp.src('./css/style.less)`. otherwise it compiles all individual less files to css in their own folders. The css injection works fine with live-reload. But when I try the browser-sync task i have the same problem.

Comment: ok I have another approach, wait. I don't know how it's in LESS, but in SCSS you only compile files which aren't prefixed with `_`, but if you have just one file which includes all others in it, your setup is fine.

Comment: I don't see that you are calling the `serve` task. do you need it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76630/discussion-between-yannick-schall-and-vsync).

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, the `runSequence` would solve your problem. Take a look here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence

You just need to add

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
```

And create a task that runs your desired ones. For example:

```
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  return runSequence(
    'less',
    ['lrl'],
    callback
  );
});
```

then

```
gulp.task('watch',['build'], function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('./**/*.less', ['build']);  // Watch all the .less files, then run the less task
});
```

Answer (score 1):

note - please do not use both **less** and **postcss** together, since **postcss** was invented to replace and enhance what **less**  does. Google it..

**Please make sure LESS files path is correct!**

Try it like this:

```
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    less         = require('gulp-less'),
    watch        = require('gulp-watch'),
    plumber      = require('gulp-plumber'),
    path         = require('path'),
    postcss      = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core'),
    csswring     = require('csswring'),
    livereload   = require('gulp-livereload'),
    browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create(),
    reload       = browserSync.reload;


gulp.task('less', function() {
  var processors = [
    autoprefixer({browsers: ["last 2 version", "> 1%", "ie 9", "ie 8", "ie 7", "ios 6"]}),
    csswring({
      preserveHacks: true,
      removeAllComments: true
    })
  ];

  gulp.src('./**/*.less')  // only compile the entry file
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(less({
    paths: ['./css/']
  } ))
  .pipe(postcss(processors))
  .pipe(plumber.stop())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
  .pipe(livereload());
});


gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('./**/*.less', ['less']);  // Watch all the .less files, then run the less task
});


// browser-sync setup
gulp.task('bs',['less'], function(){
  gulp.src('./css/style.less')  // only compile the entry file
  .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "http://my-site.dev/"
    });
    gulp.watch("./css/*.less", ['bs']);
    gulp.watch("./js/script.js").on('change', reload);
    gulp.watch("./templates/*.php").on('change', reload);
});

// run default task with live reload for local development
gulp.task('default', ['less', 'watch']); // Default will run the 'entry' watch task
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried both suggested answers above but to no avail. I can't manage to create a "less" subtask to be shared with the "live-relaod" and "browser-sync" tasks (It does re-run all tasks all the time and i loose the benefits of css injection).

The best I managed to do is to run them together like this:

```
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    less         = require('gulp-less'),
    watch        = require('gulp-watch'),
    plumber      = require('gulp-plumber'),
    path         = require('path'),
    postcss      = require('gulp-postcss'),
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer-core'),
    csswring     = require('csswring'),
    livereload   = require('gulp-livereload'),
    browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create(),
    reload       = browserSync.reload;


gulp.task('less', function() {
  var processors = [
    autoprefixer({browsers: ["last 2 version", "> 1%", "ie 9", "ie 8", "ie 7", "ios 6"]}),
    csswring({
      preserveHacks: true,
      removeAllComments: true
    })
  ];

  gulp.src('./css/style.less')  // only compile the entry file
  .pipe(plumber())
  .pipe(less({
    paths: ['./css/']
  } ))
  .pipe(postcss(processors))
  .pipe(plumber.stop())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
  .pipe(livereload());
});


gulp.task('watch', function() {
  livereload.listen();
  gulp.watch('./**/*.less', ['less']);  // Watch all the .less files, then run the less task
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
      //files: "**/*.css", 
     files: ['**/*.js', '**/*.php','**/*.css'], // is this better than gulp watch?
      proxy: "http://leadgen.dev/node/1272"
    });
    //gulp.watch("./js/script.js").on('change', reload);
    //gulp.watch("./templates/*.php").on('change', reload);
});

// run default task with live reload for local development
gulp.task('default', ['less', 'watch', 'serve']); // Default will run the 'entry' watch task
```

So now I have both tasks running together. 
I would still prefer to be able to switch between one or the other though.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same issue with stylus. You can try two `dest`, it may help

```
 gulp.src('./css/style.less')  // only compile the entry file
  .pipe(less({
    paths: ['./css/']
  } ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
  .pipe(postcss(processors))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
  .pipe(livereload());
});
```